# Construction Quote Log

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm reworking my company's log of the proposal's we send out.
Trying to indicate the total dollars that we could conceivably be awarded.
The challenge I'm having goes something like this:
We are a vendor and bid our product to installers that are themselves bidding on construction projects.
In a given month there may be ten projects where we offer pricing to say five installers.
Ten projects with five installers each = 50 quotes  -  but still there's only 10 quotes (projects) that we could conceivably be awarded.
Additionally, commonly each project can go through something like two revisions before it's awarded.
This means that we end up sending 100 quotes - but still there's only the ten projects we could be conceivably be awarded.
How can I derive the total of just the potentially awardable projects?
Is there a way to indicate only the latest awardable dollar revision of a quoted project in an "Awardable $" column?
A simplified version of what I'm hoping to accomplish like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwey1t94fh8f96i/Quote%20Log.jpg

Comment: How do you determine which is the last one? is it the R1, R2 in the Quote or just the straight row number? Why doesn't row 5 have a value (last 1000.XYZ quote) or row 11 (last VNS Installer)?

Comment: Each unique four digit 'Quote #" prefix should only have one "Awardable $" value. This would be regardless if there are multiple customers quoted - still only one "Awardable $" per unique four digit 'Quote #" (ok to be the first occurrence identical occurrences). But also the "Awardable #" value should also only be from the highest numerical value in the "Rx" suffix if the "Quote #" has this suffix.

Comment: Perhaps more simply put: I want the "Amount Quoted" value per row to appear in the "Awardable $" cell in same row. However I only want one value per each unique four digit prefixed "Quote #". And I only want the value that has the highest numerical value of the "Rx" suffix if it has one.

Comment: I still don't understand why row 11 doesn't have awardable $ as the 1004 appears to be unique to me.  So for any 4 digit quote number you just need to find the one with the highest rev number and select that correct?  and for only one customer

Comment: You're right - row 11 should have "1003.VNS" instead of "1004.VNS".

Comment: For any 4 digit quote number just need to find the one with the highest rev number (if it has one) and select that, and for only one customer. Quote numbers without a rev number should only have one "Awardable $" value even if multiple customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have a solution for you.

It's not as clean as it probably could be but it will work.  It uses a helper column which simplifies the quote number.  Assuming the quote number is in column A and this function is in column E

```
=LEFT(A2,4) + IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))=1,0,RIGHT(A2,1))/10
```

The left gives the actual quote number.

The if checks how many "." there are with the len-len(substitute) thing.  If there is 1 period it is assumed to be rev0 if not it uses the right digit as the rev number (will only work upto rev9).

It divides the rev number by 10 and adds it to the quote so you will have a column of data which has numbers like 1000.0,1000.0,1000.1,1001.0, etc)

The assumed value column will use

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E2)=0,IF(COUNTIF($E$1:$E$7,E2+0.1)=0,D2,""),"")
```

This sees if there are any of the same simplified quote number above it, if there are the cell is blank.  If there are not count if there are any cells in the range that equal the number+0.1 (next rev) if there are not this cell should be filled in with the value.

Let me know if you have problems implementing.

Comment: Thank you very much. The Public Library R1 and R2 were both showing the $6,750 value. But I changed your formula with "[Quote '# Code]" in lieu of your "$E$1:$E$7", and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer if you are satisfied so people can see it is closed.  And yes the E$1:E$7 should be the full range of the quote number column

Comment: Ok, rookie question:
How do I indicate on this forum I've accepted your answer?

Comment: The working file is here if anyone is interested:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzg6vns9xq88mns/2014%20Quotes_WIP_v2.xlsx

Comment: There should be a check mark you can select under the voting up and down triangle at the left of the answer